# Service cannot be started. System.IO.FileNotFoundException

Tags: c#, wcf, service, windows-services

I want to host my WCF Service using a Windows Service, but when I want to start my Windows Service then I get the following error in Event Viewer:

> Service cannot be started. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not
>   load file or assembly 'RahatWcfServiceLibrary, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. File name:
>   'RahatWcfServiceLibrary, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' at RahatWindowsService.Service1.OnStart(String[]
>   args) at
>   System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.ServiceQueuedMainCallback(Object
>   state) WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF. To enable assembly
>   bind failure logging, set the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1. Note: There
>   is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure
>   logging. To turn this feature off, remove the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

Comment: Do you have the file `RahatWcfServiceLibrary.dll` in application path?

Comment: Is this a pathing issue? Bear in mind that [the current directory for a Windows service is not what you expect](http://haacked.com/archive/2004/06/29/current-directory-for-windows-service-is-not-what-you-expect.aspx/)

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, How can I do this?

Comment: After a very long time of head breaking, I finally realized that the service was pointing to the "obj" folder instead of the "bin" folder!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure the `RahatWcfServiceLibrary.dll` accessible from the service. It can be at the same directory; it can be in GAC; or it can be in some dirs of `%PATH%`. See [How the Runtime Locates Assemblies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: could you please explain more? I am new to C#.

Comment: If your service is executable file, try placing the assembly in the same directory. You can check "Path to execute" property of the windows service to find out the directory. Hope it helps

Comment: The error has changed: Service cannot be started. System.InvalidOperationException: Service 'RahatWcfServiceLibrary.ServerDateTime' has zero application (non-infrastructure) endpoints. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no service element matching the service name could be found in the configuration file, or because no endpoints were defined in the service element. ...

Comment: Well, have you tried to add the `.config` file with those WCF endpoints? It is named the same as the executable file but with `.config` extension. (It true it's useless to have a WCF service without ways to access it.)

Answer (score 0):

Check if that **.dll** is on the same path as **"Path to executable:"**.

1. Go to **Services** (Press Windows Key + R, then type **services.msc**)
2. Locate your Service
3. Right click on the service and go to **Properties**
4. Check the **Path to executable:** path
5. Copy the missing **.dll** into that path
6. Click again **Start** on the Service

And you will get the service up and running.